# Could not find Chromium (rev. 1108766)

Tags: devops, google-chrome-headless, angular-test

azure devops build pipeline throwing error as Could not find Chromium (rev. 1108766) while running angular test command (npm test ---browser=chromeheadless). even i configured pupperteer.conf.js file with chromeheadless, could you please help me on this.

attaching kamas.conf file and pupperteer config file.

```
pupperteer config file:

const {join} = require('path');

/**
 * @type {import("puppeteer").Configuration}
 */
module.exports = {
  // Changes the cache location for Puppeteer.
  cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, '.cache', 'puppeteer'),
  //PUPPETEER_CACHE_DIR={path:join(os.homedir(), '.cache', 'puppeteer')},
};
```

```
kamas.conf:
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
process.env.CHROME_BIN = puppeteer.executablePath();
module.exports = function (config) {
  cacheDirectory: join(__dirname, '.cache', 'puppeteer'),<sup>your text</sup>
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        // you can add configuration options for Jasmine here
        // the possible options are listed at https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/Configuration.html
        // for example, you can disable the random execution with `random: false`
        // or set a specific seed with `seed: 4321`
      },
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage'),
      subdir: '.',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'html' },
        { type: 'text-summary' },
        { type: 'lcovonly' },
        { type: 'cobertura' }
      ],
      check: {
        global: {
          statements: 80,
          branches: 80,
          functions: 80,
          lines: 80
        }
      }
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit'],
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: '', // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
      outputFile: undefined, // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
      suite: '', // suite will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
      useBrowserName: true, // add browser name to report and classes names
      nameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the name attribute in xml testcase element
      classNameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the classname attribute in xml testcase element
      properties: {}, // key value pair of properties to add to the <properties> section of the report
      xmlVersion: null // use '1' if reporting to be per SonarQube 6.2 XML format
    },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    singleRun: true,
    restartOnFileChange: false
  });
}; `
```

Answer (score 0):

Have tried a lot of suggestions including https://hume.dev/articles/puppeteer-google-cloud-functions-v2/ , https://www.zachleat.com/web/chromium-missing/ and many other finally followed the way from the https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/9533.

Had to roll back from puppeteer 19.11.1 to the the old puppeteer version 18 and add it as the dependency to the package.json like this:

"dependencies": {
"puppeteer": "^18"
},

**100% not the best solution**, but just got tired of looking for a better way to resolve the issue, as now I always have "npm WARN deprecated puppeteer@18.2.1: < 19.4.0 is no longer supported"

Answer (score 0):

Like Dimitrij, Rolling back to puppeteer18 also solved it for me!

It solves all the errors with not being able to find chromium.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).